What hat did Lightning Hopkins wear on the cover of the "Texas Blues Man" album?
For some blues history work I'm doing, I want to determine the style of this hat:

It seems to have some characteristics of a fedora or a trilby, but none of the images I've seen on various hat sites quite match what Lightning Hopkins is wearing. Note the absence of any curl-up on the brim, and the pinch in the crown is toward the back rather than front.
Here's the description of the album on Wikpedia.
